# DIV inside td doesn't find parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs.
My structure is like this (inside larger table - just showing one cell):

```
   <td>
    <div>
    <label>OU5NS1E2IE1L</label>
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"
    ng-click="DeleteElementFromSession($event);"></i>
    </div>
  </td>
```

When calling `DeleteElementFromSession` this line of code:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent()
```

returns `DIV`, which is correct. But I want to return `<td>` element, where `DIV` is inside. I don't know why, call to this doesn't return `<td>` element? It doesn't return anything:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent().parent()
```

`<i>` is inside `DIV` and `DIV` is inside `td` so in my opinion, this should work, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: you could use instead `$(event.currentTarget).closest('td')` but if it doesn't work, then rendered HTML markup is different than the one you posted, maybe because it is malformed or invalid.

Comment: try: $(event.currentTarget).parents('td');

Comment: @Havihavi - this doesn't work either. REally strange.

Comment: @FrenkyB thats really weird.. i use that all the time, allthough i do a $(document).on('click') approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you need parent with closest:

```
   $(event.currentTarget).parent().closest('td')
```

Comment: you need to show me complete html so that i can determine which parent you want

Answer (score 1):

According to Angular JS doc:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

> parent() - Does not support selectors

parent is from jqLite which contains some of the jQuery functions.

According to jQuery doc:

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

> This method is similar to .parents(), except .parent() only travels a
>   single level up the DOM tree.

so only one level up travels is allowed.

Comment: What about nesting .parent() ? $(element).parent().parent() - this should be going up one level each time.

Comment: @FrenkyB $(element).parent() result will not support selector , .parent() is also one of the selector, so you can't use nesting .parent()

Answer (score 1):

The browser is eliminating the `<td>` node from the DOM because it is not legal HTML.

The `<td>` node needs to be a child of node of `<table>` and `<tr>`.

```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td id="tdNode1">
         <div>
            <label>OU5NS1E2IE1L</label>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"
            ng-click="DeleteElementFromSession($event);">CLICK HERE</i>
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Then the browser will include the `<td>` node in the DOM and `elem.parent().parent()` will find the `<td>` node.

```
app.controller("myVm", function($scope) {
    var vm=$scope;
    vm.DeleteElementFromSession = function(e) {
        var elem = angular.element(e.currentTarget);
        vm.id = elem.parent().parent().attr("id");
    }
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40o0f9k4/).